# VHDL : Array of records with variable field length size

Tags: vhdl, test-bench

I am trying to implement a generic std_logic_vector data logger for a testbench. This component would generate an output signal for each signal logged.

Each signal should be of the type t_probe

```
type t_probe is record:
  min_delay : time;
  max_delay : time;
  num_exp_words : integer;
  trig_lvl : std_logic;
  data: std_logic_vector;
  done : std_logic;
end record;
```

Would like to have a probe array record type:

```
type t_probe_array is array(0 to c_n_probes - 1) of t_probe;
```

Now , I have the problem of declaring a st_probe signal type which has the "data" field constrained:

```
signal coarse_probe : t_probe
```

Will obviously crash when launching simulation. Can anyone indicate how to define and initialize such an array?

thanks!

Comment: It will not crash. It will not compile. In VHDL all objects must be constrained when they are declared. And an array must have the same subtype for all elements. Does it have to be a signal? there is a workaround here if you can use variables...

Comment: Not sure I understand what is your problem.. is it with having unconstrained array sizes in the record? If so, VHDL 2008 does support that ...

Comment: @mbrandalero He wants it so that in an array, each element has a different size. That is not possible.

Comment: Could you just make `data` suitably large so that it was big enough for any purpose in your system?

Comment: Thanks scary_jeff .That would probably be the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

It is assumed that this is required for simulation only?

Then you could work with variables and access types (probably the workaround @Tricky was mentioning above?).

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity tst014 is
end entity tst014;

architecture sim of tst014 is
    type pstring is access string;
    type rec is record
        ps      : pstring;
    end record;
    type rec_array is array(natural range <>) of rec;
begin
    p : process
        variable recs     : rec_array(1 to 3);
    begin
        recs(1) := (ps => new string'("Hello"));
        recs(2) := (ps => new string'("World!"));

        report "recs(1).ps.all = " & recs(1).ps.all severity note;
        report "recs(2).ps.all = " & recs(2).ps.all severity note;
    end process p;
end architecture sim;
```